# Make a delay while listening to en event in c#

Tags: c#, xamarin

I have the following code snippet, which is a listener :

```
locationManager.DidRangeBeacons += HandleDidRangeBeacons;
```

I have a Xamarin mobile app that detects iBeacons. Once I click a button, the method `HandleDidRangeBeacons` keeps on running since it is a  listener. How can I make a delay after each execution ? This is because, its draining my battery.

```
 private void HandleDidRangeBeacons(object sender, CLRegionBeaconsRangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Beacons.Length > 0) // beacons length > 0
        {
            foreach (var b in e.Beacons)
            {
                if (_foundBeacons != null && _foundTrackers.Count > 0)
                {

                      _foundBeacons?.Add(new DetectedBeacon
                            (b.ProximityUuid.ToString(), "", b.Major.ToString(), b.Minor.ToString(), string.Concat(b.Major, b.Minor),null));                
            }
        }
      }
    }
```

**Edited**

```
private void SetupBeaconRanging(string uuid)
    {
        locationManager = new CLLocationManager();
        locationManager.AuthorizationChanged += LocationManagerAuthorizationChanged;
        var rUuid = new NSUuid(uuid);
        _rBeaconRegion = new CLBeaconRegion(rUuid, uuid);

        var eUuid = new NSUuid(uuid);
        _eBeaconRegion = new CLBeaconRegion(eUuid, uuid);

        _rBeaconRegion.NotifyEntryStateOnDisplay = true;
        _rBeaconRegion.NotifyOnEntry = true;
        _rBeaconRegion.NotifyOnExit = true;

        _eBeaconRegion.NotifyEntryStateOnDisplay = true;
        _eBeaconRegion.NotifyOnEntry = true;
        _eBeaconRegion.NotifyOnExit = true;

        locationManager.DidRangeBeacons += HandleDidRangeBeacons;
        locationManager.RequestAlwaysAuthorization();
    }
```

Comment: I'm not sure, what are you doing. Can you edit your question and show us the body of HandleDidRangeBeacons metod?

Comment: The post has been edited :)

Answer (score 2):

Here is my basic rate limiting code. Note that it is designed to run in a seperate thread.

```html
integer rate = 20;
DateTime dueTime = DateTime.Now.AddMillisconds(rate);

while(true){
  if(DateTime.Now >= dueTime){
    //insert code here
 
 //Update DueTime
 dueTime = DateTime.Now.AddMillisconds(rate);
  }
  else{
    //Just yield to not tax out the CPU
    Thread.Sleep(1);
  }
}
```

For a Event you propably just want to cut it down to the if block itself (so most calls simply do nothing).

If you want a certain minimum delay, just to avoid multiple calls in a short time: Let the event start a timer, if it is not already running. But at that point you may reach the poitn where just polling this whole thing on a timer becomes more feasible anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You would have to unregister the handler at the beginning of the event handler and re-register it again after your designed delay:

```
locationManager.DidRangeBeacons -= HandleDidRangeBeacons;
//your operations
await Task.Delay(1000);
locationManager.DidRangeBeacons += HandleDidRangeBeacons;
```

Comment: Can I put this `locationManager.StopRangingBeacons(_rBeaconRegion);` in between ? 

It is the `StartRangingBeacons` that is draining my battery.

Comment: I guess that should not be any problem. In such cas you may even just call `StopRangingBeacons` at the beginning and `StartRangingBeacons` at the end instead of the event unregistration and reregistration

Comment: Zikmund : See my edited post. Please advise where I can call `StopRangingBeacons` and `StartRangingBeacons`.